# function passed in tkinter after() method can't give return value

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to replace sleep() with after() but I need to create a function which will give me a return value that I can store and I can't figure out how. Let's take this code :

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

def test(i):
    o=i*2
    return o

print(root.after(5000,test,6))

root.mainloop()
```

This results in this output:
`after#2914` which is a string

What can I do? I tried storing the return of the function in a first variable like so:

```
v=test(6)
print(root.after(5000,v))
```

but this error pops up:
`'int' object has no attribute '__name__'`

I also tried using threading instead of after() but it doesn't solve the initial problem (the tkinter window stops responding during sleep).

Comment: How about **w.after(5000,print(v))** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will easier for you/

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

def test(i):
    o=i*2
    label.configure(text=o)
    return o

root.after(5000,test,6)
 
label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Result will be shown here")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()

test(6)
```

Screenshot before countdown:

[image]

Screenshot after countdown to 6 seconds:

[image]